# How do i get all divs attr id from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want jquery to give me ALL `ID` attr of divs from the page?

I have something like this

```
var divs = $('div').attr('id');
```

this returns as no child objects ?

**Html File**

```
`   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="select">
    <div id="comp_select">
        <div id="language">
            Language: {{view PortalComp.selectView}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you only iterate over the ones who has an id, use `div[id]` as selector, like this:

```
var ids = [];
$('div[id]').each(function(){
    ids.push( this.id );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, `attr` returns a string, not a collection. Secondly, it only returns the desired attribute value of the *first* element in the collection it is invoked from. Use `each` to iterate over the collection before feeding the values into an array.

```
var arr = [];
$('div').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
arr = arr.filter(function(i,v){return v});
```

EDIT: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15690481/1726343) points out correctly, precautions need to be taken to ensure you do not have empty array values from divs with no ID. In my example I have filtered out empty values using `filter`, but a better approach is to use a narrower selector, i.e. `div[id]`.

Comment: see my edited html part it still returns as no child objects or empty array if i try other solutions provided as answers

Comment: I am using ember+jquery and i suspect it does not take .each function and for the same reason it returns empty array .. do you know how can i solve this ?

Comment: @user2125700 `.each` should work regardless of whatever other libraries you are using with jQuery. Are you sure you are running the script after all the elements have loaded? Is the script placed in the head or at the end of the body?

Comment: my scripts are all at the end of body tag.. the snippet u provided works except that it does not run inside `.each` function

Comment: @user2125700 I'm not sure what you mean by "it does not run inside `.each` function". Are you putting this code inside another `.each`?

Comment: @user2125700 Also, the modified HTML you say you have edited into your question isn't HTML at all. Could you please post the exact javascript you are using?

Comment: i am using handlebars expression in ember and no i am not using other.each but i have figured what my problem is .. the page is not loaded when i am calling the method so it has no ids to iterate over and thus it returns empty array..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**:

```
$("div").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**Markup**:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/UGbHB/

Comment: The OP wants to store the ID values, not sequentially alert them.

Comment: The OP says nothing about storing IDs. Seems like his problem is getting the ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = jQuery.map($('div[id]'), function(el) {
    el.id;
});
```